# JS/HTML ButtonText.InnerHTML does not respond

Tags: javascript, html

I'm running into a problem. Next to the "Show More" there is an icon. When pressed it disappears, because the innerText gets overwritten so I tried this

```
document.getElementById("toggleButtonPersonal").buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>";
```

After adding this, when the button is clicked nothing happends.

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleText()


{
    
    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "Show Less";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerText = "Show More";
        status = "less"
    }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;">
    test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;"> 

</div
</body>
```

Comment: USE "Show Less <i class='fas fa-caret-up'></i>";

you need to use single quote for that

Comment: For starters.....look in your browser console at the error thrown for clues. Always report errors when code isn't working

Comment: What is `buttonText` in your code?

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0);"` on a button is pointless, just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a typo here

```
"Show Less <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>";
```

Change quotes around class to single quotes like

```
"Show Less <i class='fas fa-caret-up'></i>";
```

```js
var status = "less";

function toggleText()


{
    
    if (status == "less") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML = "Show Less <i class='fas fa-caret-up'></i>";
        status = "more";
    } else if (status == "more") {
        document.getElementById("textArea").style.display = "none";
       document.getElementById("toggleButton").innerHTML = "Show More <i class='fas fa-caret-down'></i>";

        status = "less"
    }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;">
    test
</div>

<button type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">Show More <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>

<div id="textArea" style="display: none;"> 

</div
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'll rely on the HTML and CSS instead of the JavaScript, you can do this simply by adding a class to the container.

This way, you can change the status of your button instead of replacing its `innerHTML`.

```js
const containerElement = document.getElementById("container");

function toggleText() {

  if (containerElement.classList.contains('less-mode')) {
    containerElement.classList.remove('less-mode');
  } else {
    containerElement.classList.add('less-mode');
  }
}
```

```css
.more-btn .less {
  display: none;
}

.more-btn .more {
  display: inline;
}

#textArea {
  display: none;
}

.container.less-mode #textArea {
  display: block;
}

.container.less-mode .more-btn .less {
  display: inline;
}

.container.less-mode .more-btn .more {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <button type="button" id="toggleButton" class="more-btn" onclick="toggleText();" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span class="more">
    See More
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="less">
    See Less
    <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
    </span>
    
  </button>
  <div id="textArea">TEST</div>
</div>
```